# Raspberry Pi OS Double Window Icon (How to remove?)

Tags: pi-3, taskbar

I just got a Raspberry Pi, and installed the OS. I was fiddling with the task-bar when accidentally I made 2 identical windows (showed only on the task-bar) for each app that was opened. I've been trying to restore it back, but till no I have been unsuccessful. So now I ask the community for help. Image is below...
[image: Look at the task-bar...]

Please help me... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove one of the Task Bar applet from Panel, do the following steps:

- Right click on the clock or start button on Panel (the task bar)
- Click **Add/Remove Panel Items**. Panel preference window will open
- Click on Panel Applets tab
- There will be two entries of *Task Bar (Windwo List)* **untick** second **Task Bar (Window List)** which will be listed after *Ejecter* applet as seen from the screenshot.
- Click **Close**.

This should solve your problem.